# Mod_Rewrite Rule (or an Alternative) For Reorganizing Directory Structure

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

The website I work on had these two pages in the past:

http://www.africananimals.com/stripes/zebras

and

http://www.africananimals.com/news/zebras

(These are not actual domain names, just examples.)

The directory structure had been recently reorganized, and the URLs for the same pages changed to:

http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/stripes

and

http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/news

I want a mod_rewrite rule (or a less resource-consuming alternative method, such as Redirect command or something similar) to benefit those enthusiasts who had both pages bookmarked with old URLs. I need this to work for both http//www.africananimals.com and http//africananimals.com/ versions of the URLs.

My solution would be this:

```
Redirect /stripes/zebras http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/stripes
Redirect /news/zebras http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/news
```

– but I'm not sure if I'm correct. Being awful at regex, and having only superficial understanding of .htaccess, I'd sure be grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request does not contain the word zebras it won't even attempt this regex (saves cpu).  This will swap stripes or zebras at the beginning and replace it at the end of zebras.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} zebras
RewriteRule ^(stripes|news)/zebras/?$ zebras/$1 [R,L]
```

The /? will make it so that it will also accept any uri's that end with a /, as directories are supposed to.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eric. This is perfect. Could you tell me, do you think the "Redirect" solution I suggested would also work, and if yes, what would be more resource-consuming in this case, using Redirect or mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes yours would work as well, Redirect (as far as I know is just a shortcut for RewriteRule ... [R,L]  I believe mine would be slightly faster though since it's only doing 1 regular expression.  You could of course just do Redirect with my regular expression.

Comment: Would that work for both www and non-www URLs? (The website is one of many websites on that server, and I want to make the rule only applies to that website.)

Comment: Yeah, that rule is domain agnostic so you could use it for www.stackoverflow.com if you wanted to.  It will redirect to whatever domain the client originally requested.  That is of course assuming it's in the .htaccess (or <VirtualHost>) for that domain.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eric! It was probably easy for you, but to me it was a major conundrum. You mentioned doing Redirect with your regular expression - could you show me how that would look? Would that be faster than alternatives?

Comment: Redirect ^(stripes|news)/zebras/?$ zebras/$1     ----- This should take just as long as the RewriteRule

Comment: Sorry, Eric, I have one more request / clarification. What if other website(s) hosted on the same server have "zebras" with "stripes" and "news" – is there a possibility of the rule being applied to a wrong website? Is there a way to secure the rule, so that it applies only to one chosen website in both versions of URL (such as "africananimals.com" and "www.africananimals.com")?

Comment: The best way to do this is to only put this rewrite code in the .htaccess or <VirtualHost> for the domains you want it to affect.  You could also add a RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?africananimals.com prior to the first RewriteCond

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much for your insight and your patience, Eric!